# PDO count is returning same value

Tags: php

I am ver new to PDO, I am trying below code to get same value we used to get in mysql using "mysql_num_rows", but that is returning "1" where it should return "0":

Below function returns "1", it should return "0"

```
public function countdata($field, $table, $where = "1") {
    $ar = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`" . $field . "`) FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE " . $where . "");
    $ar->execute();
    $cnt=$ar->fetchColumn();
    return $cnt;
}
```

Comment: You mean the code above returns 1? Or the mysql_num_rows, cause you know there is a difference between COUNT() and mysql_num_rows right? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772791/mysql-num-rows-always-returns-1

Comment: PDO has function for row count

Comment: I think your code is just right, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question, as well as a superstition behind it, is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110637/285587)

You don't actually need neither mysql_num_rows, nor rowCount, nor this *insecure* function of yours. It is well-written, I have to admit - much better than usual stuff that posted here. But it bears an essential flaw - it doesn't support prepared statements - the only reason for using PDO, after all.

And, as it mentioned above - it is just useless. If you think it over, you will see that every time you want to have something from such a function, you already have it.

Answer (score -1):

this souhld work:

```
public function countdata($field, $table, $where = "1") {
$ar = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`" . $field . "`) FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE " . $where . "");
$ar->execute();
$cnt=$ar->rowCount();
return $cnt;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure? Cause it looks like that will return 1, cause the SELECT COUNT() SQL will return just one row with one value, which will be the amount of rows.

Comment: i didn't look at the query, my bad