# Display MySQL column value count only

Tags: php, mysql, count

How do I display this query result:

[image: result]

from MySQL onto a webpage, just like this:

[image: this]?

I want to display the count only. I did run the same query through PHP but its returning '2'. The PHP code is below

```
 <?php
    //Connection for database                                          
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "aaaaa", "db");

    $query = "SELECT `gender`,COUNT(`gender`)  FROM `reg` GROUP BY `gender`";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
        
        if ($result) 
        { 
            // it return number of rows in the table. 
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
            
            if ($row) 
                { 
                    printf("" . $row); 
                } 
            // close the result. 
            mysqli_free_result($result); 
        } 
    
        // Connection close  
        mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Please note that I have gone through other answers like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772791/mysql-num-rows-always-returns-1) but I can't really find my way through, I want the value count only not the total number of all rows in the table, .e.g. count for 'Male'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [mysqli_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), which returns the number of rows in the result, not the actual data in the result. For that you need to use [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Your could would become:

```
    $query = "SELECT `gender`,
                     COUNT(`gender`) AS `count` 
              FROM `reg` 
              GROUP BY `gender`";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    
    if ($result) { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $gender = $row['gender'];
          $count  = $row['count'];
          echo "$gender = $count<br>";
        } 
        mysqli_free_result($result); 
    }
```

Note that I slightly changed your query to make the count accessible.